# Find out when an R package was first released on CRAN?

Tags: r

How can I find out when an R package was first released on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/)? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367649/determine-number-of-versions-in-history-of-r-package-on-cran) question is related, but does not answer my question. And I don't believe the `citation` function helps either.

Comment: Go to its CRAN page and click on the archive link.

Comment: I wish this was directly on the CRAN page, next to the "Published" date (of the current version)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the crandb API https://github.com/metacran/crandb

URL call https://crandb.r-pkg.org/MASS/all

with `jq` on the CLI

```
curl https://crandb.r-pkg.org/MASS/all | jq '[.versions[]][0].Date'
#> "2009-05-06"
```

OR in R

```
library(jqr)
curl::curl_download( 'https://crandb.r-pkg.org/MASS/all', (f <- tempfile()))
jq(paste0(readLines(f), collapse=""), "[.versions[]][0].Date")
#> "2009-05-06"
```

OR in R with `jsonlite`

```
jsonlite::fromJSON("https://crandb.r-pkg.org/MASS/all")$versions[[1]]$Date
#> [1] "2009-05-06"
```

Answer (score 2):

In a similar sense to your link you can use this:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
nCRANArchived <- function(pkg) {
 link <- read_html(paste0("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/", pkg))
 link %>%
  html_node('table') %>%
  html_table() %>%
  select(`Last modified`) %>%
  filter(`Last modified` != '') %>%
  head(1)
}


nCRANArchived('dplyr')
#     Last modified
#1 2014-01-29 21:24
nCRANArchived('data.table')
#     Last modified
#1 2006-04-15 00:03
nCRANArchived('tableHTML')
#     Last modified
#1 2016-06-26 09:30
```

Answer (score 1):

I am more of a `data.table` user so here is the `rvest` solution with a little bit of `data.table` and `anytime`:

```
R> url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rcpp"
R> dat <- setDT(html_table(html_node(read_html(url), "table")))
R> dat[, Date := anytime(`Last modified`)][ !is.na(Date), .(Name, Date)][1:10,]
                 Name                Date
 1: Rcpp_0.6.0.tar.gz 2008-11-06 19:15:00
 2: Rcpp_0.6.1.tar.gz 2008-11-30 20:19:00
 3: Rcpp_0.6.2.tar.gz 2008-12-04 09:19:00
 4: Rcpp_0.6.3.tar.gz 2009-01-11 20:11:00
 5: Rcpp_0.6.4.tar.gz 2009-03-02 09:54:00
 6: Rcpp_0.6.5.tar.gz 2009-04-03 11:41:00
 7: Rcpp_0.6.6.tar.gz 2009-08-04 16:22:00
 8: Rcpp_0.6.7.tar.gz 2009-11-08 19:23:00
 9: Rcpp_0.6.8.tar.gz 2009-11-10 11:15:00
10: Rcpp_0.7.0.tar.gz 2009-12-20 10:58:00
R>
```

By now the `Date` is a `POSIXct` so you can also compute, sort, diff, aggregate, ... on it at will.

Comment: Please leave the `R> ` as it is standard with code snippets in JSS, and I happen to agree with that standard.

Comment: No problem. I had less pleasant editing wars with other people here in the past. :-/

Answer (score 1):

```
library(htmltab)

foo = function(pkg){
    url = paste0("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/", pkg, "/")
    suppressWarnings(min(na.omit(lubridate::ymd_hm(htmltab(url, 1)$`Last modified`))))
}

foo("ggplot2")
#[1] "2007-06-01 14:27:00 UTC"

foo("tidyverse")
#[1] "2016-09-09 18:07:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `available.versions()` function in the `versions` package to see all versions of a package on and the dates they were uploaded to CRAN:

```
library(versions)
available.versions(c("treemap", "treemapify"))
```

If you need to extract that datum (i.e. only the date when a package was first released on CRAN), you can do so as follows:

```
ver <- as.data.frame(available.versions("beepr"))
ver[nrow(ver), 2]
# [1] "2014-06-25"
```